# Google scripts use replaceText function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this function that returns all the sheets that don't contain *.

I would like to replace some text in the results.

The results show all my sheets without a * like "Client < 25", "Client < 50" etc

I want to get the result: "< 25" so remove "Client" from it.

```
function SheetNamesFiltered(avoid_memoization) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  .map(sheet => [sheet.getName()])
  .filter(sheetName => !sheetName[0].match(/\*/));
}
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
    function SheetNamesFiltered(avoid_memoization) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  .map(sheet => [sheet.getName()].replaceText("Client ", ""))
  .filter(sheetName => !sheetName[0].match(/\*/));
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `replaceText` during map, I separated them.
First, getting the `sheetName` with no `*` and next is removing Client using `replace` in all results.

```
function SheetNamesFiltered(avoid_memoization) {
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  .map(sheet => [sheet.getName()])
  .filter(sheetName => !sheetName[0].match(/\*/));
  // Separated replacement in every item in array result
  array.forEach(function(item){
    item[0] = item[0].replace("Client ", "");
  });
  Logger.log(array);
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Sheets:

[image: sheets]

Comment: Great thank you!
I just changed the end to return the result with return array;